# Remote debugging a Java application

Tags: java, debugging, remote-debugging

I have a java application running on linux machine.  I run the java application using the following:

```
java myapp -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000, suspend=n
```

I have opened port 4000 for TCP on this Linux machine.  I use eclipse from Windows XP machine and try to connect to this application.  I have opened the port in windows also.

Both machines are on the LAN but I can't seem to connect the debugger to the Java application.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46171836/1619407

Answer (score 532, accepted):

**Edit:** I noticed that some people are cutting and pasting the invocation here. The answer I originally gave was relevant for the OP only. Here's a more modern invocation style (including using the more conventional port of 8000):

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n
<other arguments>
```

**Note:** With `address=8000` (as used above), the debug server will only listen on `localhost` (see [What are Java command line options to set to allow JVM to be remotely debugged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138511/)). If you want the server to listen on all interfaces, to be able to debug across the network, use `address=*:8000`. Obviously only do this on a restricted, trusted network...

Original answer follows.

---

Try this:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000,suspend=n myapp
```

Two points here:

1. No spaces in the `runjdwp` option.
2. Options come before the class name. Any arguments you have after the class name are arguments to your program!

Comment: [Official JDPA Connection and Invocation Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html#Invocation)

Comment: @DJGummikuh Nice! I've updated the post to use the newer-style `-agentlib` option for your cutting-and-pasting pleasure. :-)

Comment: Do we always need to have the source code for the remote app to be present in the machine where we do remote debugging ?

Comment: You need to _know_ the source code. Either you have the .java files or you have the .jar / .class files combined with the decompiler. IDE such as Eclipse can have a decompiler such as JDecompiler installed so that you can debug the .class file as if it's a .java file (excluding the comments).

Comment: what about java9+ applications optimized with jlink?

Comment: How can we run shell script by passing the below parameters ?

Comment: What if the java process is not started with thoses arguments int the first place? Can I somehow make the said jvm instance debuggable?

Comment: Worth repeating a comment from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/138518/500902, "Since Java 9 "address=1044" is not always listening on all interfaces. "address=*:1044" makes Java 9+ behave like Java 8" to allow debugging from different host

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to emphasize that **order of arguments is important**, for me `java -jar app.jar -agentlib` command didn't open debugger port, but `java -agentlib -jar app.jar` did

Comment: Suggested updated to this answer.... I had to modify this solution to work for connecting to java on a windows machine with multiple network interfaces.  Only setting address=*:4000 allowed me to connect to the java process from my IDE on another computer.  My final working solution is '-Xdebug Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=*:4000,suspend=n'.

Comment: anybody else has been coming back to this page for years to copy/paste?

Answer (score 95):

For JDK 1.3 or earlier :

```
-Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=6006
```

For JDK 1.4

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=6006
```

For newer JDK :

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=6006
```

Please change the port number based on your needs.

From [java technotes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html#Invocation)

> From 5.0 onwards the -agentlib:jdwp option is used to load and specify
>   options to the JDWP agent. For releases prior to 5.0, the -Xdebug and
>   -Xrunjdwp options are used (the 5.0 implementation also supports the -Xdebug and -Xrunjdwp options but the newer -agentlib:jdwp option is preferable as the JDWP agent in 5.0 uses the JVM TI interface to the
>   VM rather than the older JVMDI interface)

One more thing to note, from [JVM Tool interface documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jvmti):

> JVM TI was introduced at JDK 5.0. JVM TI replaces the Java Virtual Machine Profiler Interface (JVMPI) and the Java Virtual Machine Debug Interface (JVMDI) which, as of JDK 6, are no longer provided.

Comment: The following works with Eclipse's default settings:

-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000

Answer (score 48):

**Answer covering Java >= 9:**

For Java 9+, the JVM option needs a slight change by prefixing the address with the IP address of the machine hosting the JVM, or just `*`:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=*:8000,suspend=n
```

This is due to a change noted in https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/9-all-relnotes.html#JDK-8041435.

For Java < 9, the port number is enough to connect.

Comment: The page attached doesn't exit

Comment: @VijayanKani Thanks I searched and found an updated page.

Comment: Quoting from the release notes you linked regarding `*`: **this is not secure and not recommended**; so you need additional measures to secure the connection, such as SSH (?), see also "[Is it safe to expose java remote debugger port to the internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33184800)"

Answer (score 33):

Steps:

1. Start your remote java application with debugging options as said in above post.
2. Configure Eclipse for remote debugging by specifying host and port.
3. Start remote debugging in Eclipse and wait for connection to succeed.
4. Setup breakpoint and debug.
5. If you want to debug from start of application use suspend=y , this will keep remote application suspended until you connect from eclipse.

See [Step by Step guide on Java remote debugging](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html) for full details.

Comment: The "Step by Step guide" in the link uses some out-of-date options.

Answer (score 16):

I'd like to emphasize that **order of arguments is important**.

`java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000 -jar app.jar` command **opens debugger port**,

but `java -jar app.jar -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000` command **doesn't**. It will pass everything after **app.jar** as command-line arguments.

Comment: I would guess that is because in your second example, everything after "app.jar" is passed as arguments into your main method

Comment: @xoXZeusXox ha ha. Yes, it passed as arguments. Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: That seems new to java 11

Answer (score 3):

This is how you should setup Eclipse Debugger for remote debugging:

***Eclipse Settings:***

1.Click the Run Button
2.Select the Debug Configurations
3.Select the “Remote Java Application”
4.New Configuration

- Name : GatewayPortalProject
- Project : GatewayPortal-portlet
- Connection Type: Socket Attach
- Connection Properties: 
  i)  localhost   ii) 8787

***For JBoss:***

1.Change the `/path/toJboss/jboss-eap-6.1/bin/standalone.conf` in your vm as follows:
   Uncomment the following line by removing the #:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"
```

**For Tomcat :**

In **catalina.bat** file :

Step 1:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Step 2:

```
JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Step 3: Run Tomcat from command prompt like below:

```
catalina.sh jpda start
```

Then you need to set **breakpoints** in the Java classes you desire to debug.

Comment: In Java 8 the JDK supports a [JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars002.html) environment variable so to enable the debugger for any Java application you need to use:

`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n`

p.s. sorry for the edits, fighting with the formatter.

Comment: Any idea about NetBeans?

Answer (score 2):

for everybody that has the problem that if you really do remote debugging from 1 machine to the other then using :

-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n

is not enough because that binds now (at least on unix/osx machines) to localhost so you can only connect to it from localhost.

If you try to remote debug this then you will get connection refused for this. From i think Java 9 on you need to do:

-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=*:8000,suspend=n

or give an ip that it needs to bind on for hat *

Answer (score 0):

Every solution here is describing the method to attach debugger after the application starts.
In the "debugger listening" setup you need to set server=n and suspend=n. If not the Gradle will throw permission denied error.

build.gradle:

```
run {
    jvmArgs = ["-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=n,address=5005"
}
```