# Eclipse : Eclipse Java Remote Debugging

Tags: eclipse, remote-debugging

I  have a question with respect to Eclipse IDE , Java Remote Debugging .

If i got all the Source Code of the Application and configure the Host , Port , located remotely ,  under Eclipse  Remote Dubugging Configuration , will the Break Points  gets Started automatcally ??

For example if i got all the  Citi Bank Source code in my Eclipse IDE and i mention the Host and Port (Production Environment) in my Remote Debugging Configiraton Will the break points will be enabled if a specific condition is met ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to normally add debug options when starting the JVM on the server to listen on a specific port, and similarly, use that same port in Eclipse.  See this prior question - [Remote Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975271/remote-debugging-a-java-application)

Comment: Thank you very much , so even if i didn't got the updated source code , it will stop if the port and host are matched , am i correct ??

Comment: Well, if your source is out-of-sync with what is deployed on the server, how will you know what you are debugging is the correct code?

Comment: to atleast some extent , i mean it atleast enters into the method name . anyway thank you  i got it .