# Eclipse : Jetty Failed to connect to remote VM

Tags: eclipse, jetty

I am trying to set up Remote Debugging Java Application .

I have downloaded Jetty 8.1 , deployed my Application into its Webapps (D:\Jetty\jetty-distribution-8.1.9.v20130131\webapps)

Now strated the Jetty Server from Command Prompt using `java -Xms1024m -Xmx4096m  -DSTOP.PORT=8024  -jar start.jar OPTIONS=All`

I want to Debug , so from  from Eclipse IDE  under Debug Configurations ,  in Remote Java Application , i provided the Host and Port as shown below

[image]

But unfortunately i am getting the following error .

Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect

Please let me know if i am making any mistake .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't start the jetty server with the right command line.

See prior answer about "Remote Debugging": https://stackoverflow.com/a/975342/775715