# How to debug spring source in a web application

Tags: spring, debugging

I want set some breakpoints in spring source file in my web application. so I can know the exactly process of spring's start.

How can I do this in eclipse?

Comment: Spring can be debugged remotely like other java application. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975271/remote-debugging-a-java-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not worked with spring web, but generally if you attach the source for class files you will be able to debug them. I have done this for Hibernate and a couple of other frameworks.

Comment: Specially if you are using Maven, since Eclipse can download the sources automatically.