# Reading a directory returns null when deployed on the apache tomcat 7.0 server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm trying to read a folder on a network and retrieve a list of txt files.
When testing it locally in Eclipse, it works fine, however whenever I deploy it on the Apache Tomcat 7 server it returns null.

It doesn't seem to be an access right problem since the server has access to the folder I'm trying to browse.
I'm not sure what is going wrong there, is it a setting on the server I need to change or something else?

```
private List<File> readDirectory() {
    File test = new File(envMap.get(database));
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    try {
        files = FileListing.getFileListing(test);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    List<File> txtFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
    if (files != null) {
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                txtFiles.add(file);
            }
        }
    }
    return txtFiles;
}
```

I used this http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=68 for `FileListing.getFileListing`

After double checking it turns out that I'm getting a `FileNotFoundException: Directory does not exist`. The directory does exists and the server has access rights on it, so I'm not really sure of what to do.

Comment: Which part is `null`? `FileListing.getFileListing(test);`?

Comment: Yes. The List<File> files is null after that.
It works fine in Eclipse, so I don't think there's a problem with the function.

Comment: Then you will have to show us how that is implemented. Also there is no point initially initializing it to `= new ArrayList<File>();` since you're reassigning it.

Comment: Does it throw the FileNotFound Exception?

Comment: Any OS differences between your local Eclipse setup and Tomcat server machine?

Comment: I used this: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=68

Comment: No exceptions are being thrown, And yes, there is eclipse is on a windows 7 while the server is running 2003 server.

Comment: Are there files in the directory on the server?

Comment: Yes. There are. EDIT: The files are on another network folder actually, not on the server that's running the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what the problem was, turns out that by default Apache is running under a Local System Account that has no network access. Changing that to another account with network access solved the problem.

Source: http://blog.mattwoodward.com/2010/08/accessing-network-drive-from-apache-and.html

Answer (score 0):

`files` cannot be `null`. Your code uses

```
static private List<File> getFileListingNoSort(File aStartingDir) throws FileNotFoundException {
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] filesAndDirs = aStartingDir.listFiles(); // may return null
    List<File> filesDirs = Arrays.asList(filesAndDirs); // would throw NPE
    for(File file : filesDirs) {
        result.add(file); 
        if (!file.isFile()) {
            //must be a directory               
            List<File> deeperList = getFileListingNoSort(file);
            result.addAll(deeperList);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Are you sure you are showing us the right code?

Comment: @Emualynk I will delete my answer, but you should definitely debug the code and check where the `null` originates.

Comment: Is there a way I can access the java console when it's running on the server (and not eclipse)?

Comment: @Emualynk Yeah, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975271/remote-debugging-a-java-application

Comment: After checking it actually does throw a FileNotFoundException this one in particular: `"Directory does not exist: " + aDirectory`