# How to communicate from Eclipse RCP to the 'host' Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-rcp, rpc

I have an Eclipse RCP application that has been started from the Eclipse IDE in debug mode. I've created a simple `SWT TreeViewer` control in the `RCP` application for presenting the cause chain and stack trace of a Throwable. What I'd like is that if a developer double-clicks a `StackTraceElement` in the viewer then the 'host' Eclipse IDE will open the appropriate file at the right line number.

The best workaround I have so far is that I can print the `StackTraceElement` to the Console *(of the IDE)*, and then click on the *(filename.java:linenumber)* to open the file that way.

**My question comes in two parts:**

1. Is there any built-in communication path from an RCP application *(in debug mode, if that's important)* back to the host IDE?
2. If there is such a path, is there some command to instruct the IDE to open the file at the right location?

I know I could write a plugin for use in the IDE, and then I could communicate with it over a socket or something like that. I'm more interested in discovering any built-in functionality I can use.

Comment: The purpose of what you are doing is a bit unclear.. Is this a related to debugging only, or is this the intended behaviour of the RCP you mention?

Comment: It is intended behaviour that the RCP application catch its own Exceptions and display all the details of it. While developers are debugging the RCP application, it would be nice to influence the host Eclipse IDE to open files that are referenced from the StackTraceElements that are accessible from the Exception.

Comment: One simple alternative can be to add a Java exception breakpoint (e.g., via the "J!" button in the "Breakpoints" view), and to use the "host" debugger to navigate the call stack.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Andy, but that's not really an alternative to the use case I have in mind. Think of it more like when you get an Exception and do a e.printStackTrace() to the Console. While reviewing the stack trace, you see filename:line number references and you want to open those files to look at the code. Sure, I can run the app again with an Exception breakpoint, but it's not the same as reviewing a record of an Exception after the event.

Answer (score 1):

If what you describe as RCP would instead be a separate plugin running in the host IDE, then the communication would be very simple and part of the Eclipse functionality. But what you describe is communication between two java processes, and thats a different thing. There are ways of course, google "java interprocess communication", but off the top of my head I cant think of anything simple and easy. I dont know how much extra work you would like to do just for making debugging your app easier.

You might wanna have a look at remote debugging aswell. That will allow you to run your RCP app separately from Eclipse and still be able to debug. See [this questions for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975271/remote-debugging-a-java-application)

Comment: Thanks. I realise that the Java processes are separate, but as there is already a communication path between the two (at least when using the debugger), I was hoping there would be something I could use. Since posing my question, I found this https://github.com/marook/eclipse-remote-control which would certainly help (except that the GPL license is a problem).