# Launch4j enable remote debugging

Tags: java, remote-debugging, launch4j

Is it possible to configure launch4j to enable remote debuggin of the resulting application depending on a command line parameter? I aware that you can achive this by having the launched application launch another java application but I would like to eliminate that overhead.

Answer (score 1):

According to launch4j's documentation one can pass additional parameters to the application using a file called *ApplicationName*.l4j.ini. 
So you could just create such a file besides your application and write the debug configuration to it ([As described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975271/remote-debugging-a-java-application)):

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000,suspend=n
```