# Beaglebone black cross development

Tags: java, debugging, cross-compiling, gpio, beagleboneblack

I heard this is somehow possible to develop and debug straight on Beaglebone black.
I do Java. At the moment I have to generate jar and copy to devboard then run. but this way I can not debug and step through the code. On local debugging also makes little sense, because I do not have those GPIOs on my laptop.

What is the solution if i do not want to connect monitor to Beaglebone.

Comment: cloud9? Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Debugging**

You can run the Java program on the Beaglebone black, and then connect to it remotely for debugging. This lets you set breakpoints, do basic hot code swaps, etc. More info:

- [Remote debugging a Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975271/remote-debugging-a-java-application)

**Remote Development**

To develop on the Beaglebone directly, you have a few options. I think this best option is to setup a file share on the beaglebone black, and use a build script or similar on the development workstation to automatically copy the recompiled class files (or jar file) over to the beaglebone black.

Another option is to set up a file share from the beaglebone to the dev workstation, and run the java program on the beaglebone using the remote class/jar files.

Yet another option is to just do all the development, including compilation, on the beaglebone black directly. However, this is slow and generally not worthwhile for java development.

Answer (score 0):

Since 8.0 Netbeans IDE has remote development possibility. [I do recommend](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-embedded.html) works on regular Java SE as well.