# Is it possible with JDeveloper to debug an executing JAR file on my PC?

Tags: java, jdeveloper

I have a JAR file that is executed with "javaw ..." and it works fine.  Is there a way with JDeveloper, or any other tool, to debug that executing file? The answers found on this board focus on Eclipse whcih I do not have.

Comment: Run the application with [remote debugging enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975271/remote-debugging-a-java-application). Connect JDeveloper to the port you specified. Profit. P.S. you can set `syspend=y` if you want the application to wait until you have connected.

Comment: Is there a way to run the JAR file that was built a long time ago in debug mode?  I have the source code and can pull that into JDev, but I can't change how it was built.

Comment: Read the link I gave you, it really isn't that long. Please.

Comment: @BoristheSpider thank you.  I read through that but it doesn't apply.  My application is running locally on my PC from a JAR file that contains CLASS files.

Comment: Ah ha, and what about `javaw -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=6006 -jar myapp.jar`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I run that in command and get nothing, the window disappears and the app doesn't start.  Is it waiting for something?  I don't see anything in task mgr either.