# running scripts against running program

Tags: java

I had a question about scripts and running programs. Would you be able to run a script against a running Java program to get data values from the running java program? Essential I use a java program that monitors electronics equipment and once a week we record data values on some of the devices. There are 8 devices we do this with and each device has 64 data points we record and I am looking to see if there is a way that you can run a script to collect this data with out disrupting the program in any way?

Appreciate any advice or insights. Thank you.

Comment: Can the Java program be modified to save the data to a file periodically?

Comment: There are a lot solutions to that. The first obvious: The program writes the data to a file or - better - a shared table in a database. Each client can then read that data at any appropriate time. Another solution: The program listens on a port for incoming requests and then serves them with the data. I fear, this question is far too broad as it is.

Comment: where does the java program record the data.A log file? Your question is incomplete and unclear. Why do you want to run a script for this?

Comment: maybe a remote debugging? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975271/remote-debugging-a-java-application

Comment: All great options but I am limited on those. The software is run from a server. I log in through a web interface. I don't have access to the software to be able to have it save to a file. Other then it being something that has been done here for years there really is no reason we save this data. The theory is that if something happens to a device we can look back and see when the changes started to help figure out why the device failed.

Comment: You can't make any software do something it hasn't be implemented to do without changing it.