# How to debug a .jar file remotely using Intellij Idea

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I am currently using intellij idea to code my project that I am working on, after creating of `.jar` file using `OneJar` command i deploy the .jar file on my linux server who address is something like `192.164.1.125`.there I run the command `sudo nohup java -jar fileName.jar &` on server to start the jar file in the background and use the rest-client app to send rest calls to  my .jar file.Whenever something goes wrong I can only see error message in `nohup.out` file and what I actually wanted is to debug my jar file using intellij idea i.e how can I debug my .jar running on `192.164.1.125` using intellijIdea running on my client machine.I know I have to use that EditConfigurations option in run menu of intellij and provide IP and Port, but how to do it exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must run the remote "java -jar .." command in debug mode by adding the additional magic flags.   You can then tell your local IntelliJ to create a new debug configuration targeting a remote application - IntelliJ provides the magic flags you need.

The help page for this feature is at https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-remote.html

Comment: I am getting `unable to open debugger port(IP:porntno) java.io.IOException`error

Comment: now its working , this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858312/handshake-failed-connection-prematurally-closed-error-when-debugging-solr-in-i really helped

Comment: The link in the answer no longer exists. Anyone know if there's an updated page?

Answer (score 5):

You can do the remote debugging on IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 version very easily!

- Click on "Run" -> "Edit Configurations"
- Click on "+" and select "Remote"
- Enter your remote IP and select source code folder path
- Optional : change the name and port of your wish

[image]

- Run your remote server jar with the command which is mentioned in the Command line arguments for remote JVM box .
  something like this,

  sudo nohup java "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8911" -jar fileName.jar &
- You are all set. add the breakpoints and click on Debug symbol to debug your remote jar from local

Comment: When running a compiled application (say one or more jars created in the maven target directory) where do I add breakpoints ? The problem I see is that the code in the src/ folder is not the one being executed. Is there a way to add breakpoints into the jar , in intellij ?