# Connect to JVM for debugging that has been spawned by a Python script

Tags: java, python, debugging, jvm, py4j

I have a Python code, which I run with IntelliJ. The Python code will execute a `java` command, which will eventually spawn a JVM. The Python and JVM communicates using Py4J and custom sockets. How can I connect to the JVM for debugging purposes using IntelliJ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your Python code spawns `java` command using [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) call. If you want to debug it from your IDE then you should turn on debugging on the spawned JVM (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975271/remote-debugging-a-java-application) topic for possible options to enable JVM debugging):

```
    os.system("java -jar your.jar -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y, transport=dt_socket,address=4000, suspend=y");
```

In above code the spawned JVM will listen on port `4000` for incoming debugger connections. Now you can use [InteliJ remote debug configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-remote.html) feature to connect to the spawned JVM using provided port. Note the **`suspend=y`** parameter - it means that the JVM will be started as suspended until debugger is connected. This will prevent the case that you miss the interesting JVM execution part you want to debug or prevents the case when JVM exited after main thread had finished before you can even started your InteliJ remote debug session.

Answer (score 1):

You execute the java command which spawns a JVM with the debug arguments.

I.e. `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044`.

Then in the IDE you create a new remote connection.
In fact, when you go about creating a new one, when you specify host and port it already gives you the arguments, such as:

> Command line arguments for running remote JVM:
>
> ```
> -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
> ```