# How do we debug java code step by step deployed in IBM MobileFirst server in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I am new to mobile app development and currently stareted developing a mobile app using IBM MobileFirst Plugin in Eclipse IDE. How can I debug the java code under server package of the project i have written for calling the backend server services? Is there a way to debug the code as is done when we debug a Java project deployed in servers such as JBoss?

Comment: Better define "java code". Java adapters in 7.0? Java code in JavaScript adapters? something else? which version?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remote debugging a Java application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975271/remote-debugging-a-java-application)

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to view the following video, which demonstrates how to debug server Java code in Worklight 6.0 and above. The video explains what requires setting up in Eclipse in order to begin debugging server-side code: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/logging_and_debugging_on_worklight_server?lang=en

If you are referring to Java adapters (introduced in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0), you need only to right-click a Java adapter, then select Debug As -> Debug MobileFirst Java Adapters: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/server-side-development-category/debugging-adapters/