# How to debug Apache Storm in Eclipse?

Tags: debugging, remote-debugging, apache-storm

We can generate storm jar using particular parameter. However, if we need to debug this project (actually a far) locally as well as remotely?

If it is simple jar, that we can debug. However, here we are deploying jar using following command:
**storm jar project.jar main_class_name**

Not sure how can we deploy storm topology, so that we can do storm project in debugging mode?

Please find updated yaml file as below:

```
 

    # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    # or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    # distributed with this work for additional information
    # regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    # to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    # "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    # with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
    #
    # http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    #
    # Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    # distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    # WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    # limitations under the License.

    ########### These MUST be filled in for a storm configuration
    # storm.zookeeper.servers:
    #     - "server1"
    #     - "server2"
    # 
    # nimbus.host: "nimbus"
    # 
    # 
    # ##### These may optionally be filled in:
    #    
    ## List of custom serializations
    # topology.kryo.register:
    #     - org.mycompany.MyType
    #     - org.mycompany.MyType2: org.mycompany.MyType2Serializer
    #
    ## List of custom kryo decorators
    # topology.kryo.decorators:
    #     - org.mycompany.MyDecorator
    #
    ## Locations of the drpc servers
    # drpc.servers:
    #     - "server1"
    #     - "server2"

    ## Metrics Consumers
    # topology.metrics.consumer.register:
    #   - class: "backtype.storm.metric.LoggingMetricsConsumer"
    #     parallelism.hint: 1
    #   - class: "org.mycompany.MyMetricsConsumer"
    #     parallelism.hint: 1
    #     argument:
    #       - endpoint: "metrics-collector.mycompany.org"

    worker.childopts:"-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8999,suspend=n"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to remote debug, you need to enable debugging in worker JVMs. See here for the correct Java flags: [Remote debugging a Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975271/remote-debugging-a-java-application)

Add this flags in all/shared supervisor `storm.yaml` to entry `worker.childopts` (it might be necessary to restart Storm cluster). **You need to make sure, that only a single worker is stared per host!** Otherwise, two JVMs want to open the same port and one will fail of course.

In Eclipse, choose `Run -> Debug Configuration` and create a new `Remote Java Application`. Specify the host and port (port must be the same as specified in `worker.childopts`) of the running worker JVM you want to debug.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try with this.

Comment: I am using default storm.yaml file coming into installation. For adding required parameters into this, I have added below parameter: worker.childopts:"java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8999,suspend=n -jar application.jar"

Comment: This will lead to following error: >Exception in thread "main" ja
va.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java
.util.Map
        at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.findAndReadConfigFile(Utils.java:141)
        at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.readStormConfig(Utils.java:188)
        at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:71)
        ... 57 more
Could not find the main class: backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus.  Program will exit.

Comment: I think I need to apply any other settings as well.

Comment: You only need to include the options without "java" and "-jar application.jar": `worker.childopts:"-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8999,suspend=n"`

Comment: I have tried with suggestion, same error is comming.

Comment: Not sure any other parameter do I need to set or not?

Comment: Can you post your yaml file (edit your question and add it there). It seems there is some formatting problem.

Comment: Please find yaml file.

Comment: It might sound stupid, but maybe you need a blank after the colon... worker.childopts: "-agentlib..." Otherwise, I cannot spot any problem in your yaml file. But the error shows, that the yaml cannot be parsed correctly. Thus, it's not a semantical problem of other missing parameters...

Comment: Can you maybe show the whole stack trace of the error. I am also wondering how the shown file can be the correct yaml file for the supervisor... It does not specify enough parameters for the supervisor to start correctly (for example, "nimbus.host" is put into comment). Where is this yaml file located?

Comment: That problem was with spaces. After that I have tried to debug, eclipse debug keeps waiting. But debug is coming in eclipse. I have put yaml file under location: apache-storm-0.9.3\conf.

Comment: "But debug is coming in eclipse" -> do you mean it does still not work? Is the yaml file only located at you local machine? You need to put it on all machines that run supervisors.

Comment: Now...Yeah. I am able to dubug it via eclipse. It seems two problems:1. nimbus, supervisor, ui were not running properly, as firing command one after another. I have kept 15seconds delay in execution. 2. when toplogy has deployed and after that if I am not starting debugging instantly, connection refused error was coming. I am able to resolve it. Thank you very much Matthias for helping in this. Appreciated!!!!

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I have a similar question, If you have any ideas, can you please advise? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32405136/how-to-debug-apache-storm-in-local-cluster-mode-through-eclipse

Comment: For me it shows connectionRefused error . Jagrut..if possible can u elaborate the steps in bit more detail. I am deploying the jar and then starting the application in debug mode using the debug configurations specified above . But it always show ConnectionRefused Error

Comment: Eclipse shows connection refused? Sounds like a firewall problem on the debug port.

Comment: No Firewall issue ..still :( ..do we have to give location of jar file as well?

Comment: Can you check the worker node if the worker JVM is running and if the port got opened...

Comment: Can anyone put the detailed steps here. I am a newbie and facing issues in understanding the steps to debug.

Comment: Did you read the "Remote Debugging" link from the answer? Do you have problem with remote debugging general, or just in combination with Storm? What did you try? What does not work? Maybe it's worth starting a new question?

Answer (score 5):

To enable debugging across the various supervisor VMs, all you have to do is edit the storm.yaml file and update the worker.childopts entry to something like:

worker.childopts: "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5%ID%"

If you had your supervisors on ports 6700,6701,6702 etc., this would create a debug port on 56700,56701,56702 etc.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have the misfortune of using Ambari, this won't work as Ambari doesn't respect the format used in the yaml file.

Comment: One thing to note is that 6700... are the default ports.

Comment: Do you happen to know how and when is the %ID% translated to the port of the supervisor?

Comment: Been away from it too long, sorry.