# Running a topology from an IDE in debug?

Tags: apache-storm

After much searching, I didn't come across anything describing how to do this or if it's a possibility. But it would be extremely helpful if I was able to launch my topology from IntelliJ in debug mode, stop at breakpoints, etc...

Is anyone aware if this is possible? Any guides on how it can be accomplished?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug Apache storm in eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226052/how-to-debug-apache-storm-in-eclipse)

Comment: are you interested in debugging a topology running in local mode or in distributed mode?

Comment: ideally distributed mode. currently i'm deploying in distributed mode while developing. but if it's easier (or possible) to debug in local mode, i would start using it for development.