# Applying a Regex Filter to Crawler to crawl specific pages

Tags: regex, web-crawler, stormcrawler

I am using storm crawler 1.10 and Elastic Search 6.3.x. For Example I have a main website `https://www.abce.org` and it has subpages like `https://abce.org/def` and `https://abce.org/ghi`. I want to crawl specifically the pages under `https://www.abce.org/ghi`.

My seed Url is `https://www.abce.org/ghi/`.

Currently I applied below different regex filters at each time.

1. `+^https:\/\/www.abce.org\/ghi*`
2. `+^(?:https?:\/\/)www.abce.org\/ghi(.+)*$`
3. `+^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?abce\.[a-zA-Z0-9.\S]+$`

I tested my regex expressions [regexr](https://regexr.com/) its shows valid. But when I check on statusindex its displaying only  discovered seed url and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [FastURLFilter](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki/URLFilters) which you might find more intuitive to use. Run the topology in debug mode to check that you do have URLs submitted to the URLFilters and that they behave as you expect.

Before you ask, [here's a tip on debugging Storm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41935603/432844)

Comment: Thank for suggesting **FastURLFilter**. I added fast.urlfiter.json and updated urlfilters.json. The crawler topology is submitted unfortunately when I check on Admin UI the under Bolts section there is no progress on fetching  or parsing. I am sharing my config files. My **urlfilters.json**  `{   "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.regex.FastURLFilter",
   "name": "FastURLFilter",    "params": {   "file": "fast.urlfilter.json"   }  }`   and **fast.urlfilter.json**  `[     {  "scope": "domain:abce.org",  "patterns": [             "AllowPath /ghi/",  "DenyPath .+"  ]  } ]`.

Comment: I checked thoroughly when I run the crawler in local mode it is crawling up to certain level and giving `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` .When I run this in remote not even crawling a single url.

Comment: I figured out the issue because of my running crawlers I killed one of my crawler and re run the **FastURLFilter** that works for me.

Comment: @an__snatcher glad to hear you got it to work. Feel free to mark the answer as useful and /  or accepted. Thanks