# How to get console logs remote java application

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm currently working on GPS tracking device which has a application running in java. I'm trying to debug the application as a remote java application.

I was able to successfully start the debug and step through the code but I was not able to get console out put to eclipse. Can you tell me how to get the console output to eclipse.

This device is connected via USB.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975271/remote-debugging-a-java-application

Answer (score 0):

log4j for logging into console.
It works for me