# Remote server debugging in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

I am trying to do remote debugging for  remote server and it's a Java application. While doing  configurations, I know the hostname and Http port number but I don't know DT_SOCKET port, using Java programming. Is there a way to find DT_SOCKET port?
Please guide me.

Screen shot of eclipse debug configuration:

[image]

Comment: First of all, are you sure that the remote application was started with debug support enabled? (eg. with the command listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/975342/222438)

Comment: am not sure..how we can confirm ?

Comment: check the running processes on the server (if on linux, `ps -ef | grep java`) and look for those arguments

Comment: thanks for guiding me...i did run  above command(ps -ef | grep java)...i have seen like "debug=true" statements ...but i unable to found socket port...please suggest me ,(info: remote  Application server(web sphere)

Comment: sorry, im not familiar with setting up websphere for debugging

Comment: Can Any one guide me....