# Debug Java code within a Windows service invoking the JVM

Tags: java, windows, debugging, service, jvm

I have a Windows service (that is, a native *.exe*) spawning the JVM, loading a bunch of JAR files and invoking their Java code.

How can I remotely debug the Java code running in the service process space?

**Note**: I tried to use the *Java Control Panel* to add the usual Runtime Parameters: `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4321,suspend=n` but apparently these are not read by the spawned JVM, since the aforementioned port is not open on my system.

Comment: Which JDK version are you using? Seems like you are using wrong parameters. Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22631355/2398521).

Comment: Consider setting `suspend=y`. This will cause the JVM to pause until the debugger has connected to your JVM.

Comment: Try `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:4321,server=y,suspend=n`, as indicated by link provided by @MaximDobryakov. And you need to tell the .exe to do that when *it* creates the VM. The Java Control Panel options don't apply there. How to tell the .exe depends on the .exe.