# Remote debugging in java error

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

I want to do remote code debugging. So I ran below command in my remote machine:

`java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8998,server=y -jar myapp.jar`.

Then I created debug config in eclipse. But I am getting a error in remote machine stating:

```
Could not find or load main method
```

I have set the buildpath of eclipse correctly. The jar has the manifest which states the correct main method in jar. Still I am facing this issue. So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, does the program by itself run correctly?
I mean, in the remote machine: java -jar myapp.jar

Second, the parameters you have used are typical for JRE1.4.
For a more advance Java version, take a look here:

[Remote debugging a Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975271/remote-debugging-a-java-application)

Comment: The program does run correctly on remote machine. I have tried command for newer jdk but had no success

Comment: Post the debug configuration from eclipse. Maybe the hostname, port or project are incorrect.