# icCube - developing a java plugin for ODATA, how to debug the server connection?

Tags: etl, iccube, olingo

We are developing a java plugin to make an Odata feed available as a data source using Olingo. There are authorization issues for the specific data provider we want to connect to, but we can not get into the tiny details to debug what is going wrong (we get a 401 authorization error and it is not so obvious on what is wrong).

We have found the advise to use Fiddler to check the network traffic, but we do not know how to use it to check the traffic between the iccube.exe process (background) and the odata provider source (https).

So the question is:
How can you debug the data traffic between icCube and the data provider (source)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to debug icCube application as a remote java process with your favorite IDE (e.g. IDEA). For this you'll need to change the configuration file (icCube.ini or icCube.sh) and restart icCube in debug mode (check [here](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/configuring_iccube/jre_options.php) - JRE Configuration ).

A post on the setttings for debugging remotely in Java :

[Remote debugging a Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975271/remote-debugging-a-java-application)