# @Around @Aspect in the same package only works with @DependsOn

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj, aspect

**Please see the updates below.**

---

I have a Spring Boot application where I accept TCP/IP connections:

```
   public MyClass implements InitializingBean {
   @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {

            while (true) {

                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();                   
                new ServerThread(socket).start();
            } 
        }
    }

    ...

    private class ServerThread extends Thread {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try (InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
                     OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream()) {

                     // Read line from input and call a method from service:
                     service.myMethod(lineConvertedToMyObject);

                } catch {
                    ...
                }
            }
    }

}
```

Now this works fine, as it is. But when I introduce AspectJ to `myMethod`:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyServiceAspect {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServiceAspect.class);

    @Around(value = "execution(* com.package.to.MyService.myMethod(..))")
    public MyObject rules(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        MyObject obj = (MyObject) joinPoint.proceed();

        logger.debug("Took {} milliseconds", System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);

        return obj;
    }
}
```

`service.myMethod` is not called and the thread is blocked. What am I missing?

**Update:**

So here's the deal: `MyService`, `MyServiceImpl` and `MyServiceAspect` are all in the same package. Moving `MyServiceAspect` into another package made it work.

Does this ring a bell for anyone? Happy to award the bounty to anyone explaining this behavior. Thanks!

**Update 2:**

Yet another solution: Adding `@DependsOn(value = {"myServiceAspect"})` on top of `MyServiceImpl` again resolves the issue, still wondering why though.

Comment: I might be able to explain it if I can see the full picture: Maven build, Sporing configuration, aspect and application code. I need to see real package names and full code, not fake packages and incomplete methods with a lot of "...". Would you mind posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing your problem on GitHub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Actual problem

As it was described by [Alexander Paderin >>](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3985168/alexander-paderin) in his answer to the related [question >>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52518312/cacheable-doesnt-intercept-the-method-cache-is-always-empty/52609074#52609074) infinite loop in the `afterPropertiesSet()` was the thread blocker, since control wasn't return back to *Spring* in this case.

### 1. Working example with your samples (not actual after question edit)

Code samples you've provided do not contain issues directly, *AspectJ* declaration is fine.

First of all, please let me share working example: [spring-aspectj-sockets](https://github.com/marme1ad/spring-aspectj-sockets). It is based on *Spring 5.1.0* and *AspectJ 1.9.1* (currently latest versions) and uses your samples, works independent of the location/package of `MyServiceAspect`.

---

### 2. Issue explanation

#### 2.1. Intro

The most possible thread blocker in your samples is a call to `ServerSocket.accept()`, javadocs for this method says:

> Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. **The method blocks until a connection is made.**

There are 2 correct ways of handling `accept()`:

1. To initialize connection first, e.g.:

   ```
   serverSocket = new ServerSocket(18080);
   clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 18080); // initializing connection
   Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); // then calling accept()
   ```
2. Set up timeout to wait for acceptance:

   ```
   serverSocket = new ServerSocket(18080);
   serverSocket.setSoTimeout(5000); // 5 seconds timeout
   Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); // then calling accept()
   ```

   **NOTE**: If within 5 seconds there will be no connections, `accept()` will throw exception, but will not block the thread

#### 2.2. Assumption

I assume that you are using 1-st approach and somewhere you have a line which initializes the connection, i.e. `clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 18080);`.

But it is called (e.g. if static declarations are used):

- After `serverSocket.accept()` in case `MyServiceAspect` is located in the same package and
- Before - in case `MyServiceAspect` is located in some other place

---

### 3. Debugging

I'm not sure if this is needed, have doubts because of bounty's description, let me cover this quickly just in case.

You can debug your application using *Remote Debugging* - it will cover aspects, child threads, services, etc. - you will only need to:

1. Run *Java* with specific arguments like it is described in this [question >>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975271/remote-debugging-a-java-application)
2. And connect to the specified debug port using IDE (steps for *Eclipse* are described in the same question)

Comment: __P.S.__: @hasan-can-saral, in case this will not help, could you please provide some additional information / code samples.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm looking for a solution to my specific problem, whereas your answer is mostly `ServerThread`? So this is highly irrelevant. I'm trying to replicate the issue and post it to GitHub. Did you see the update? Apart from that there are no issues with my socket implementation.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral, thank you for the update, but it is still not enough information, it is not clear how you instantiate `serverSocket` on your side from the line `Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();` Let me please wait for the MCVE then.

Comment: As far I've used all your code samples within my example, which works independent of `MyServiceAspect`'s package.

Comment: Updated the question one more time. I am initializing `ServerSocket` in `afterPropertiesSet` method of `InitializingBean`.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral, so you might/will have a race condition here because of `serverSocket.accept()` - it will block the thread until socket listener will be created. As I wrote earlier please add `serverSocket.setSoTimeout(1000); // 1 seconds timeout` - it will wait for a second to instantiate connection with a socket listener, then will go to the `ServerThread` logic where listener instantiated, then will try to accept once again.

Comment: Also you can simply check if `serverSocket.accept()` is the reason of the blockage without debugging, just by adding two outputs around that line: `System.out.println(1); Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); System.out.println(2);`

Comment: I have checked, it is not. I think it has more to do with Spring black magic rather than `ServerSocket`. Moving the class into another package makes it work. If it were due to a race condition or a timeout (which I cannot btw, since this is a server and it would exit if there were no connections within 1s) moving packages wouldn't help.

Comment: Sorry, so both outputs (`1` and `2`) are shown, correct?

Comment: Correct, regardless of the aspect working or not. I honestly think that this has nothing to do with `ServerSocket`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181060/discussion-between-marme1ad-and-hasan-can-saral).