# IntelliJ debug Java application in Docker

Tags: java, debugging, docker-compose

I'm new to this. Can you tell me how to set up a debugging Java program that runs in Docker?

The project is built with the help of Maven after which Docker uses `*.war` to run the program.
As far as I understand it, IntelliJ must be pushed remotely for debugging.

[image: container]

docker-compose.yml :

```
# myapp (Wildfly + Keycloak + myapp)
  myapp-myapp:
    image: myapp/wildfly-myapp:wf11
    container_name: myapp-myapp
    depends_on:
      - myapp-postgres
      - myapp-mailhog
    environment:
      TZ : Europe/Paris
      KEYCLOAK_URL: http://localhost:8080/auth
      WILDFLY_PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
      JAVA_OPTS: 
      DB_CONNEXION_URL: jdbc:postgresql://myapp-postgres:5432/myapp_db
      DB_CONNEXION_URL_DELIMITER: "|"
      DB_HOST: myapp-postgres
      DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
      KEYCLOAK_DB_CONNEXION_URL: jdbc:postgresql://myapp-postgres:5432/keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_DB_CONNEXION_URL_DELIMITER: "|"
      KEYCLOAK_DB_USER : keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_DB_PASSWORD : keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_DB_NAME : keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_DB_HOST: postgres
      APP_CLUSTER: "false"
      JGROUPS_EXTERNAL_ADDRESS: 10.178.27.30
      JGROUPS_TCP_EXTERNAL_PORT: 7600
      JGROUPS_TCP_BIND_PORT: 7600
      JGROUPS_DEFAULT_STACK: tcpping
      JGROUPS_INITIAL_HOSTS: "10.178.27.30[7600]"
      WILDFLY_CLUSTER_PASSWORD:
      WILDFLY_NODE_NAME: myapp-master
      SMTP_HOST: myapp-mailhog
      SMTP_PORT: 1025
      SMTP_FROM: ${SMTP_FROM}
      SMTP_USERNAME: ""
      SMTP_PASSWORD: ""
      myapp_LOG_LEVEL: "ALL"
      myapp_DEBUG_LEVEL: "ALL"
    volumes:
       - ./myapp/data:/opt/jboss/myappdata
       - ./myapp/logs:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/log
       - ./myapp/deployments:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments
       - ./myapp/configuration/myapp-admin.properties:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/myapp-admin.properties
       - ${ST_SRC}:/opt/jboss/myappdata/${PROVIDER_CODE}/frontend/st
       - ${CC_SRC}:/opt/jboss/myappdata/${PROVIDER_CODE}/frontend/cc
       - ${SC_SRC}:/opt/jboss/myappdata/${PROVIDER_CODE}/frontend/sc
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "7600:7600"
```

Comment: Do you create the Dockerfile yourself or use a library?

Comment: This might be helpful [Debug java application running in Docker from IntelliJ](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/04/debug-your-java-applications-in-docker-using-intellij-idea/)

Comment: Hmmm, you could add the Java Arg in my answer after `JAVA_OPTS:` and include the port 8000 under `ports:`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can enable remote debugging with the following JVM-Argument

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n
```

Then you can attach the Intellij Debugger with `Run` -> `Attach to process`
Your application should have the port specified (8000 in this case)

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/975342/3257988) for more information

**For this example (Docker-Compose with Wildfly)**

```
environment:
  ...
  JAVA_OPTS: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n
  ...
ports:
  - "8000:8000"
  ...
```

**In General**

*Docker*

For usage in Docker, you additionally have to expose the port

```
EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n", "/path/to/my/java.jar"]
```

and then

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 <image>
```

*IntelliJ* (starting 2019.1)

This procedure can now be done automatically by IntelliJ
https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/04/debug-your-java-applications-in-docker-using-intellij-idea/

Comment: I have this like a container : 
46aa7c658b99        myapp/wildfly-myapp:wf11   "/opt/jboss/docker-e…"   22 hours ago        Up 5 hours (healthy)   1883/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7600->7600/tcp, 4000/tcp, 9990/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp

Comment: How do you get your code from IntelliJ into the Docker Container? Did you write a Dockerfile? Do you use a Maven plugin?

Comment: and I use `docker-compose up` for run all containers

Comment: So are you using containers you didn't create yourself? If yes, which containers?

Comment: It would be very helpful, if you included all you steps, and the docker-compose.yml in the question post

Comment: I build a `*.war` file with Maven `package`