# Unable to open debugger port error in intellij

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, port, remote-debugging

I have been trying to remotely debug my application. My application is on remote linux server. I am not sure what's the debug port of application on that server. I tried almost every port I could think of but the host server refuses to connect.

How do I approach this? Should I try to find the debug port? If yes, how do I do it. Is there any command to open or set or find it on the server. I tried searching through questions and everything. I did not find anything that could resolve my problem. Whatever I try, the host still refuses to connect.

Comment: How do you run your aplication on the remote server?

Comment: I deploy using the application and then start the application using cash command to start any profile I need.

Comment: What command do you use to start application?

Comment: You need to use the debug flag to specify a port when starting the app in Linux to enable the remote debug. See here https://stackoverflow.com/q/975271
If a command would add it for you, you need to check its command to find that debug port.