# IntelliJ IDEA JSP validation

Tags: jsp, intellij-idea

I'm trying to turn on JSP validation in my IntelliJ IDEA, version 12.1.4, Community edition. I've read on their page where it's possible, but it doesn't work for me so I know I need to change my settings. I looked at [JSP debugging in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739/jsp-debugging-in-intellij-idea) but it's for an older version and the tabs/settings that are referred to, I can't find. Here's what they say on their site: 
JSP validation

All JSP pages from a web application can be validated with the help of the embedded Jasper JSP compiler. Validation is invoked as part of make/rebuild/compile actions which you can trigger in

JSP development just as you do for straight Java development. If an error is found, the convenient view lets you navigate directly to its occurrence in the corresponding JSP page, opening the page in the JSP editor if necessary.

But it doesn't tell you how to turn it on!

Comment: You might be out of luck here, that feature is only in the premium edition. Comm. edition was never intended for Servlet/JSP dev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the [Ultimate Edition directly supports Java EE functionality](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).