# How to evalute JSTL EL expression when debugging JSP page?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

Suppose, I've set a breakpoint in a JSP page. The debugger has stopped at that line. How to evaluate JSTL EL expression in a debug session instead of sending result to a browser every time the expression is being changed?
I use IntelliJ IDEA. Habitual 'ALT+F8' (evaluation window) doesn't work.

UPD: in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739/jsp-debugging-in-intellij-idea) thread the questioner said 'The debugger never hits' the breakpoints. But in my case the execution stops, but I don't know how to evaluate EL expression without sending the result to a browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSP debugging in IntelliJ IDEA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739/jsp-debugging-in-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating of the code of the class generated by Tomcat based on my JSP file I found 2 ways:

1. If you want just to check the value of a request param used in an EL expression you can type into "Evaluate Expression" window the following:
   `((PageContext) pageContext).findAttribute("paramName")`
   or other "get" method of *javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext* class instead of *findAttribute()*.
2. If you want to evaluate the exact expression type the following:
   `org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate("${yourExpressionHere}", java.lang.String.class, _jspx_page_context, null, false)`
   but before you have to add Tomcat's library *jasper.jar* into you project. Class *org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl* is described in Tomcat's API docs.