# Debugging JSP with intellij IDEA

Tags: jsp, debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea

I want to debug a JSP which is running in a server(based on tomcat 7.0.92). I am using IDEA ultimate 2019.1

I tried the approach suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/a/23781314/11414612 but still when loading the page, debug points are not working. I am not sure whether I have set the web facet correct. There are several modules written as OSGi bundles in the source code and whenever I add a new web facet from module settings, it asks to choose the module and It gets added to the modules section under the selected module.[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/029gf.png)

Can someone help me how to set these configurations?

Another thing that I noticed was although I cannot connect to the port without the server being started (expected behavior), when the server is down, debugger is still connected to the port until I stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally used Eclipse to debug.